# C++ : declare members static or not ? performance with virtual inheritance?

Tags: c++, multithreading, inheritance, virtual

I develop a C++ code whose main object will be called in a larger program.
Only one instance of the object needs to be created within the host, so I have been declaring all class variables and methods as static.

- My first question is a best practice question : is it a good idea to do so in term of performance, portability, maintainability ?

  On the one hand, the drawback with static members is that it becomes difficult to implement multithreading as these members would be shared by all threads. On the other hand, redeclaring all members as non-static would require to make some inheritances virtual, which brings to the second question.
- I know that virtual methods have their cost, but what about the virtual inheritance itself ? Does virtual inheritance affect performances ?

Thanks for your attention.

Best regards.

Comment: Ever heard of singleton? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: @GargAnkit Since singleton is a proven anti-pattern, I suggest you do not bring it up.

Comment: Everything has its own pros and cons. Not sure if it will be useful for the OP in this particular situation, considering the complete application.

Comment: Singleton is like the worst solution he can choose, it's avoidable 99,9% of time. I don't understand why you need virtual inheritence tho, can you describe it a little more?

Comment: @GargAnkit Singleton has nothing to do with the principles asked here. Moreover CRTP might be relevant.

Comment: Virtual methods have runtime overhead which can indeed be noticible. However, virtual inheritance is purely a compile-time construct. These two techniques have very little to do with one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it a good idea to do so in term of performance, portability, maintainability ?

No - it looks like you're making things more complex than necessary.

> Only one instance of the object needs to be created within the host, so I have been declaring all class variables and methods as static.

Rather than declaring everything static, there is a pattern known as the [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) which achieves what you need. Declare your class as normal, and just create a single instance.

> I know that virtual methods have their cost, but what about the virtual inheritance itself ? Does virtual inheritance affect performances ?

There is a very small cost to dispatching virtual methods, but in the vast majority of cases, it is dwarfed by the computation. This is very much premature optimisation - don't worry about the overheads unless you are certain it's a major cost. Profile first, then optimise. [Virtual inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) is a very particular solution to multiple inheritance and the 'diamond problem', but there is insufficient information here in the question to know if that is even relevant to your problem.

Comment: Singleton is anti-pattern and should be banned. Downvoted for mentioning of it.

Comment: Also, I'd like to understand what this statment is based on: "...what about the virtual inheritance itself? ... There is a small cost"

Comment: A much simpler pattern is - if you need one instance, create only one instance.

Comment: @SergeyA Blanket statements, banning well-understood patterns, and downvoting the mere mention of them isn't particularly helpful, especially without substantiation or offering a better alternative. Some good points are made in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx but I still think there are times when the singleton pattern can be justified. Anything can be used well and abused (operator overloading, for example).

Comment: @SergeyA "There is a small cost" was referring to virtual methods. I've clarified the post to draw the distinction. I suspect the poster didn't really mean virtual inheritance proper, as there is no mention of multiple inheritance. Unfortunately, there is insufficient information in the question to really give a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

On today's system virtual methods and inheritance don't have a large impact, unless you expect to call virtual functions a lot (more than millions of times per second).

Static members tend to create problems for maintainability.

What's best is usually to start with the simplest implementation and see how it performs.

Comment: Virtual methods can actually have huge impacts because the compiler will be (mostly) unable to inline them. Also the cost of vtable is huge for small objects.

Comment: @Melkon you need to call the methods lots of time to see the difference. There's an extra pointer for small objects. Unless you have a virtual class for single bytes this is not going to matter. Say you have 10M objects (which is a lot) on a 64 bit system you waste an extra 80 MB which is nothing today.

Comment: Sure, i worked in a codebase where virtual keyword was at everywhere... even if there was barely any function which was called so much times, it adds up. I rather avoid declaring anything virtual if i don't have a good reason to use them. I think it's overused.
For huge objects it's obviously not a problem, i spoke about SMALL objects.

Comment: Vitrual methods incur terrible performance implications. Not because of (double) dispatch, but because since compiler doesn't see the definition, it will not optimize the code.

Comment: *for the huge object thing i just speak about the vtable itself. And it's not about 10 million objects, it's just ridicolous when the vtable give you a 20-50-100% size overhead. It's inefficient, and we don't use C++ to be inefficient. The same for virtual calls, i don't want to pay for something unless it's a must.

Comment: @Sergey - WHAT?! How does adding a `virtual` keyword to a member function hide that function from the compiler? Do you think `struct x { virtual int f(){ return 5} };`will have "terrible performance"?

Comment: @BoPersson, of course it will. Since compiler will have no idea (generally) which version of f will be called (unless called non-virtually, but why would someone do this) it will be an optimization block - no code will be moved past this function or before it, nor will it be simply optimized away and replaced with constant in the register.

Comment: @Sergey - Of course it can be optimized and inlined `x obj; obj.f();` is easy for the compiler to handle.

Comment: @BoPersson, this is non-virtual call. But if you have a virtual function, you are not likely to call it non-virtual manner (otherwise, why bother with declaring it virtual to begin with)?

Comment: Most of the time the overhead is negligible (ms in a program that takes minutes or kB where you're used XXX MB of RAM) and your time is better used optimizing something else. Benchmark your code and then see what needs to be optimized. And yes sometimes it will be these things, but not often.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you really understand multithreading. Static methods are not problematic for multithreading, in no way they are. They behave exactly like free-standing functions, and on themselves have no multithreading problems. Also, I fail to see the need to use a class with all static members - free-standing functions in the namespace will be better.

Comment: I agree, there is no problem with multithreading in general, in my case I avoided any non-static variable so that all threads would also share some working arrays, whereas it would not be the case with multiple instances. I could mark the working arrays as threadprivate with openmp though.